# Recognizing overlapping objects

Tags: python-3.x, image, opencv, contour, image-recognition

I am processing an image with **OpenCV** on **Python** and I want to count every objects (worms) on it. Worms are rather light beige whereas the background is black (see picture) so it is rather easy to distinguish them. The problem is that sometimes worms are too close to each other (sometimes they even overlap) and *cv.findContours()* will draw one big contour instead of two smaller ones (see picture below).

Because I am using *cv.foundContours()*, I have to first turn the picture into black and white, then blur it (optional) and finally threshold it in order to have white worms in a black background.

I am using the following code :

```
import cv2 as cv
img = cv.imread('worms.jpg')
gray = cv.cvtColor(img, cv.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
blur=cv.GaussianBlur(gray,(5,5),1)
ret,osu = cv.threshold(blur,0,255,cv.THRESH_BINARY+cv.THRESH_OTSU)
imsource,contours,test = cv.findContours(osu,1,1)
cv.drawContours(img,contours,-1, (0,0,255),2)
```

I tried to erode the thresholded picture but it doesn't work well since the "bond" between two worms is quite big.

[image: Picture Processing]

Thanks for the help

Comment: It seems more a classification issue than a segmentation one. Do you have a database with ground truth or just this image ?

Comment: Do you mean a picture of the background itself empty ? I can have one but I am not using it. Do you think I should use another approach ? I dont have any knowledge in machine learning

Comment: Classifier such as SVM or KNN needs some data to train in order for them to learn what features does fit with the class you are looking for.
Depending if it is accuracy CNN's approaches offer more accurate results but needs also much more training data.
If you prefer to stay with "traditional" computer vision, take a look to template matching.
Template matching may give you good results depending of the context but I would still suggest to you to try classification approaches because more generic (specially CNN's approaches).

Comment: Maybe combining with [edge detection](https://opencv-python-tutroals.readthedocs.io/en/latest/py_tutorials/py_imgproc/py_canny/py_canny.html#canny) can help to make a distinction

Comment: Thanks a lot, I will definitly try this, classifier + edge detection